# Gradle sync failed after installing new windows and android studio (Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM')

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I installed windows 11 and android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 4. But after adding my previous project i got an error on gradle sync

"Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE, ML_MODEL_BINDING)
"

Here's my build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
            options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

)

Here's my build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33
    lint {
        baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\admin\\.android\\release.keystore')
            storePassword ''
            keyAlias ''
            keyPassword ''
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.nexuscorppg.getquiz"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    namespace 'com.nexuscorppg.getquiz'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.7.0'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1"
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7")
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I already update my gradle to latest stable and also update all plugins but still getting this error